# JS: Join text; but enclosed in span tag

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this function: `function output(string) {...}`, and suppose I also have `var name`. How can I do the following: `output("Hello" + name)` such that name is enclosed in a `span` with a `class`?

Comment: You will need to show an example of what you have tried so far.